# Was the Spider-Verse arc inspired by Spider-Man: The Animated Series?

Tags: spider-man, inspiration, marvel, spider-man-tas, spider-verse

In [Spider-Man: The Animated Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(1994_TV_series)) season 5 during Spider Wars, we learn about parallel universes with different versions of Spider-Man and they fight a common evil. This arc seems quite similar to Spider-Verse storyline from the comics.

So, was the Spider-Verse storyline inspired by Spider-Man: The Animated Series?

Comment: According to wikipedia, the comic story-line was in fact based on Spider-Man: TAS (specifically the last two episodes). Unfortunately, the only source provided is fandom.com.

Comment: @Raj noticed that but I was looking for some proof if we can get

Comment: @Raj do you have evidence?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Not Really**

When Dan Slott, the writer of the 2014 "Spider-verse" event was asked about inspiration for his comics he replied -

> As Slott tells it, the inspiration for the storyline came from him wanting to tell his version of the plot from the video game Spider-Man: Shattered Dimensions as a comic book. In the video game, an artifact called the Tablet of Order and Chaos caused cross-dimensional trouble for four versions of Spider-Man: Spider-Man, Spider-Man Noir, Ultimate Spider-Man and Spider-Man 2099.

He revealed more information on [this](https://twitter.com/DanSlott/status/1099802025603280896?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1099802025603280896%7Ctwgr%5Ed5021705579dac14f385c70d102f3781f5889464%7Ctwcon%5Es1_&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cbr.com%2Fdan-slott-spider-verse-history%2F) Twitter thread.

When asked directly about Spider Man: The Animated Series -

[image]

This actually kind of upset John Semper who [wanted credit](https://www.cbr.com/spider-man-animated-series-john-semper-credit-spider-verse/) for creating the whole Spider Verse.

Answer (score -5):

The idea of multiple dimensions has been around long before Spider-Man. Peter had also crossed paths with alternate realities in the past. I doubt that it was based on, but it was probably at least slightly inspired by the show.

Comment: But in the show a bunch ( 5 or 6) of Spider-Man come to same place  similar to spider-verse rather then one or two spider-man version corssover

Comment: The show was trying to do an adaptation, albeit a very loose one of the clone saga, which was very big in the 90's.

Comment: The Clone Saga in Other Media
In Spider-Man: The Animated Series, Miles Warren creates clones of Hydro-Man and Watson in "The Return of Hydro-Man" (episodes 59-60), but they degenerate in the end. A more cosmic Clone Saga takes place in "Spider Wars" (episodes 64-65), when Spider-Carnage tries to destroy the Multiverse.   http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Clone_Saga

Comment: This answer lacks credibility. Maybe look into some sources and answer sans opinion.