# In the comics is Spider-Man special in that there is always a different version of him across realities?

Tags: marvel, comics, cartoon, spider-man, parallel-universe

I'm only asking about the comics, but I distinctly remember from watching Spider-Man: The Animated Series growing up, that Spider-Man was somehow special in that there were alternate versions throughout the multiverse.

As a child, I never fully grasped if that was unique to Spider-Man, or if that was merely because he was the star of the show? There was [Madam Web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madame_Web#Television) who seemed to imply the former, but I don't know how or if this was translated from the comics.

I know, for instance in one comic universes, Peter Parker

> becomes The Lizard, and Gwen Stacey becomes Spider-Gwen

Or in another universe

> he dies and is replaced by Miles Morales?

So is it unique to Spider-Man that every universe has its own Spider-Man connected in someway, whether they are Peter Parker or otherwise? Or are there just as many versions of other heroes or individuals? For example, does each universe have its own uniquely different version of Captain America and Hulk or is Spider-Man somehow special in some other way that gives him different versions in different realities?

As a note, I'm asking this in preparation of watching Spider-Man: No Way Home, so I would appreciate no spoilers or details from any of the films.

Comment: Could you provide a quote of the statement (from the animated series) that you have in mind, for context? Or specify the episode you have in mind? If you can't recall/determine the title of the episode, can you describe the basic plot of the episode?

Comment: @LogicDictates it was more a consistent theme than any one episode or quote. You may need to have watched multiple seasons and been reading the comics for a long time to be able to answer this.

Comment: Are you sure it was indicated that there was a version of Spider-Man in every reality? I just watched the final two episodes, in which Spider-Man encounters variant Peter Parkers for what was apparently the first time, and there was no indication in those episodes that Spider-Man existed in every reality. In fact, we were shown a reality where Spider-Man was just a fictional character, played by an actor.

Comment: @LogicDictates I didn't say each version was a super hero. Also, I think what I'm getting/recalling at is that all versions are somehow connected via a 'web' or realities?

Comment: There is something called the [Web of Life and Destiny](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Web_of_Life_and_Destiny) in the comics. It's supposedly the source of power for every Spider-Person variant across the Marvel multiverse.

Comment: @LogicDictates that could be it

Comment: Something something Spider-totem, or what have you.

Comment: According to the Marvel Fandom page, the Web of Life and Destiny was first mentioned in the _[Spider-Man: Shattered Dimensions](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Man:_Shattered_Dimensions)_ video game in 2010, long after the mid-'90s animated series.

Comment: (I don't know if this should be a comment or an answer. It's mostly speculation but I shouldn't be answering in the comments either) The way I see it, there is a Spider-Man in nearly all realities the same way the others are also in nearly all realities, save for some exceptions. Take Earth-1218 for example, which is the designation given to our world within Marvel. As far as I know, Spider-Man is just a fictional comic book character... unless I was lied to my whole life.

Comment: It seems the animated series did it first.  Documentary https://youtu.be/m0cWibGpMHI

Comment: @lucasbachmann - The '90s animated series was the first instance of Spider-Men from different universes teaming up. But the concept of the Web of Life, or all Spider-People being connected through the Web of Life, wasn't introduced until later comics.

Answer (score 6):

This is really hard to answer. We have seen universes without other heroes, such as the Sony movies that (Spoiler for SM NWH)

> just got merged with the MCU, and both Spider-Man were confused by the mention of the Avengers and other heroes beside Spider-Man, as well as Venom being confused at the mention of other Superheroes

so we absolutely have universes with only Spider-Man. (We can probably safely assume, that the movies all exist in the Marvel Comic Universe somewhere, as most shows and games also get to exist in the Universe).

*Edit: As of the release of Doctor Strange: Multiverse of Madness, this part also gets more complicated, as the MCU main universe is now officially called 616, which is the comic main universe, however, there are comics that are not part of comic 616 about the MCU and other Marvel movies. At the time of first writing this answer, it was already mentioned in Far From Home that the MCU universe is 616, but as the whole multiverse stick in that movie turned out to be bogus made up by Mysterio and his gang, i assumed that was also completely made up by him. So there is evidence the MCU is part of the comic multiverse, but there is conflicting information from the MCU itself.*

However, there are also universes where Spider-Man does not exist, like most shows that do not feature Spider-Man as the main character, as well as some older Marvel movies that are inside their own universe.

If we talk comics the answers gets a little bit more complicated and less clear. Here, in the Spider-Verse event, we learn that the multiverse is held together by the Master-Weaver weaving the Web of Life and Destiny and that [Spider-Totems](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Totems) (of which the [current comics equivalent of Madam Web](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Julia_Carpenter_(Earth-616)) is one) are kind of a constant. BUT a lot of Spiders were already killed by the inheritors, leaving their universe without a Spider-Totem. So while in here, we learn every universe HAD a Spider-Totem...not every universe still has a Spider-Totem anymore.

However, later on we get a bit of a different explanation for the multiverse in the comics in the Secret Wars event from 2015. So the question is: does the Master-Weaver REALLY weave all universes? If yes, we can safely assume the Spider-Totem is a constant, while we saw universes that did not have different versions of other heroes. And with a bit of imagination, we can assume that these universes, in which we did not yet see a Spider-Totem, still have one, but they are staying under the radar (like Ezekiel did), are in hiding (like Ezekiel put Silk in hiding), or the universe will eventually have one in the future. If the Master-Weaver however does not Weave all universes, we can assume that the Spider-Totem is kind of special in that regard, but there are universes out there that never had or ever will have a Spider-Totem, just like we saw universes where certain heroes did not exist.

Comment: I clicked that spoiler and then hit refresh just in time to not get spoiled! This is a fantastic answer — exactly the sort I was interested in getting. Does Madam Web or the events from the cartoon factor in, on anyway? Can you go into more detail about what the spider totem is? My comic tbr list is long, but I'm not as concerned about spoilers there.

Comment: @AcientSwordRage explaining the totems would be too much for this answer, but I will update my answer to link to [inlcude this link](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Totems) for the totems. Madam Web is just a Spider-Totem with a very special connection to the Web of Life and Destiny, giving her some extra abilities ([current Madame Web](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Julia_Carpenter_(Earth-616)))

Comment: If nothing succinct can be added, then a link out to the wiki page is much better. Mind if I edit in about Madam Web? It's one of the things I mentioned in my question and feel it would be good to include

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Are you sure editing the answer is a good idea? You're going to see the spoiler in the edit window.

Comment: @Clockwork now I know it's there I can avoid reading that bit

Comment: Tagentially, did you think you could answer this? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/141051/3804

Comment: @AncientSwordRage sorry, but I don't have much behind the scene knowledge.

Comment: @Lofter no worries, thanks for having a look